# The dragon Curve sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary

The [dragon curve sequence](http://oeis.org/A014577) (or the regular paper folding sequence) is a binary sequence.  `a(n)` is given by negation of the bit left of the least significant 1 of `n`.  For example to calculate `a(2136)` we first convert to binary:

```
100001011000
```

We find our least significant bit

```
100001011000
        ^
```

Take the bit to its left

```
100001011000
       ^
```

And return its negation

```
0
```

## Task

Given a positive integer as input, output `a(n)`. (You may output by integer or by boolean).  You should aim to make your code as small as possible as measured by bytes.

## Test Cases

Here are the first 100 entries in order

```
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: [someway related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20744/34531)

Comment: The least significant bit of `100001011000` is a `0`. Do you mean the least significant `1`?

Answer (score 18):

### Mathematica 25 Bytes

```
1/2+JacobiSymbol[-1,#]/2&
```

Other ways of doing this:

56 bytes

```
(v:=1-IntegerDigits[#,2,i][[1]];For[i=1,v>0,i++];i++;v)&
```

58 bytes

```
1-Nest[Join[#,{0},Reverse[1-#]]&,{0},Floor@Log[2,#]][[#]]&
```

Comment: Wow! A mathematica answer and it's not builtin only. Have an upvote!

Comment: The only thing that could make this answer even better is an explanation for why and how it works. :P

Comment: @MartinEnder https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5770.pdf See the remark after Example 13.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

1 byte thanks to ETHproductions.

```python
lambda n:n&2*(n&-n)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcixCoAgFAXQva94U/nKQBMapP6kxShLqJuIS19vY2c88c3nA1P8vJTL3evmCBb10ArUPXjSxT@JAgVQcjh2oaVWim1MAVmozovAcsc2N9Rw9e@gzchcPg)

Bitwise arithmetic ftw.

Comment: "You may output by integer or by boolean" so I guess you don't need the `0+(...)`?

Comment: The order of operations here is really confusing me. Could `n&1` be put in parentheses? Or is is `1+(n^~-n)<1` that can be put in parentheses? Or is it `1+(n^~-n)`...

Comment: oh god what. this is what I was looking for :o nice!

Comment: `&` has the lowest precedence, so it is `1+(n^~-n)`

Comment: Ah, found the precedence table. Now it all makes sense :P

Comment: @ETHproductions done.

Comment: So how does it work?

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <del>38</del> <del>34</del> 29 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+`^(1+)\1$|1111
$1
^1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi0s7IU7DUFszxlClxhAIuFQMueIMVf7/N@Qy4jLmMuEy5TLjMuey4LLkMjTgMjI0NgMA)

Martin and Leaky essentially came up with this idea, for 5 more bytes off!

Converts the input to unary, and then progressively divides the number by 2. Once it can't do that evenly anymore (i.e. the number is odd) it then removes patches of 4 from the input, computing the result of the last operation mod 4. Finally, this checks if the result was 1, which means that digit to the left of the least significant 1 bit was zero. If that is true, the final result is 1, otherwise it is zero.

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi0s7IU7DUFszxlCFS8WQC8gGAk0tQ5X//w25jLiMuUy4TLnMuMy5LLgsuQwNuIwMjc0A) (should I post it myself?)

Comment: I found a way to avoid the full binary conversion and instead just divide out the factors of 2 and check for equality with 1 (mod 4): https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi0s7IU7DUFszxlClxhAIuFQMueIMVf7/N@Qy4jLmMuEy5TLjMuey4LLkMjTgMjI0NgMA

Comment: @MartinEnder essentially my algorithm... with 2 bytes off

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh yeah, they're both the same idea. Great minds and stuff... ;)

Comment: I'll edit that in, but if either of you wants to post it I'll revert, as I probably wouldn't have thought of that myself ;)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
&N&HṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/NT83j4c62/4YGBofbHzWt8f4PAA)

#### How it works

```
&N&HṆ  Main link. Argument: n

 N     Negate; yield -n.
&      Bitwise AND; compute n&-n.
       This yields the highest power of 2 that divides n evenly.
   H   Halve; yield n/2.
  &    Bitwise AND; compute n&-n&n/2. This rounds n/2 down if n is odd.
    Ṇ  Take the logical NOT of the result.
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 8 bytes

```
I2z1xnO@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/9/TqMqwIs/f4f//BwtnAAA)

Takes input [as the code point of a Unicode character](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values) and outputs the result as a 0x00 or 0x01 byte accordingly.

For testability, here is a decimal I/O version at 12 bytes which uses the exact same algorithm (only I/O is different):

```
/o
\i@/2z1xn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/nysm00HfqMqwIu//fyNDYzMA)

If Alice was a golfing language and didn't require explicit I/O and program termination, this would clock in at a mere 5 bytes (`2z1xn`) beating both 05AB1E and Jelly.

#### Explanation

```
I    Read input.
2z   Drop all factors of 2 from the input, i.e. divide it by 2 as long
     as its even. This shifts the binary representation to the right
     until there are no more trailing zeros.
1x   Extract the second-least significant bit.
n    Negate it.
O    Output it.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
g~(a:b:c)=1:a:0:b:g c
d=g d
(d!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P71OI9EqySpZ09bQKtHKAMhMV0jmSrFNV0jhSrPVSFFU1Pyfm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioJGbWKCQphBtoKdnaRmr@R8A)

Uses 0-indexing.

Comment: What does the `~` do in this context?  I get that it is a lazy match, but why do you need a lazy match?

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
f n=even$div n$2*gcd(2^n)n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzza1LDVPJSWzTCFPxUgrPTlFwyguTzPvf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQm5igUKaQrShnp6pQex/AA)

Boolean output.

**32 bytes**

```hs
(d!!)
d=d%1
~(h:t)%k=k:h:t%(1-k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyNFUVGTK8U2RdWQq04jw6pEUzXbNtsKyFDVMNTN1vyfm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioJGbWKCQphBtoKdnaRmr@f9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

Saves one byte off of [Anders Kaseorg's recursive-list solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132818/20260).

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>24 23</s></sup> 21 bytes

```apl
{~⍵[¯1+⌈/⍸⍵]}0,2⊥⍣¯1⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v7ruUe/W6EPrDbUf9XToP@rdAeTG1hroGD3qWvqodzFQ4lHXov9pj9omPOrte9TV/Kh3zaPeLYfWGz9qm/iob2pwkDOQDPHwDP6fdmjFo97NhgYGAA)

Bitwise operations are a bit long in APL, so I went with the method in the question.

-1 byte from dzaima.

-2 bytes from Adám.

### Explanation

```apl
{~⍵[¯1+⌈/⍸⍵]}0,2⊥⍣¯1⊢ input n taken on the right
               2⊥⍣¯1⊢ n in binary
             0,       with 0 prepended in case the LSB is at first index
{           }         do the following to the array ⍵:
         ⍸⍵           get indices of 1's in ⍵
       ⌈/             find maximum index
    ¯1+               subtract 1 from it to get the previous index
  ⍵[       ]          Find the element at that index in ⍵
 ~                    bitwise NOT
```

Comment: `2(⊥⍣¯1)⊢` -> `11⎕dr⊢` and maybe rm `0,`

Comment: @ngn `11⎕DR` doesn't work because the chunks of 8 bits are in LSByte-first order, which is quite different from the result of `2⊥⍣¯1`.

Comment: @Bubbler right, `⎕dr` here requires an assumption that the machine is big-endian

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
b0Ü¨θ≠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/yeDwnEMrzu141Lng/38jQ2MzAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise), <s>28</s> <s>20</s> 16 bytes

```
::-~^~-&:[?>]~-^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K88sTv3/36rOyiquTtfKXi3aKi7OzqpOEciMjatTtFGz@///v6ExAA)

### Explanation

This is a port of Leaky Nun's Python answer.  It unfortunately does not work on TIO because TIO's version of the interpreter is a bit outdated.

We start by making 3 copies of our input with `::`, we then decrement the top copy by 1.  This will flip all the bits up until the first 1.  We then xor this with another copy of our input.  Since all of the bits up until the first 1 on our input have been flipped this will result in all those bits being 1 on the result.  If we then add one `~-` to the result we will get a single 1 at the place *to the left of* our least significant 1.  We AND this with the input to get that bit from the input.  Now we will have `0` iff that bit was off and a power of 2 iff that bit was on, we can change this into a single `1` or `0` with `:[?>]`.  Once this is done we need only negate the bit `~-^` and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 39 bytes

*6 bytes saved thanks to nimi*

```hs
f x|d<-div x 2=[f d,mod(1+d)2]!!mod x 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoibFRjcls0yhQsHINjpNIUUnNz9Fw1A7RdMoVlERyAZJ/M9NzMyzLSgtCS4pUknOz0tOLFGJVldQtyrOyC8HGlFho5ubWKCQFm2op2doYBAb@x8A)

Comment: You can use `div` instead of `quot`.

Comment: Even better: `divMod`: `f x|(d,m)<-divMod x 2=[mod(1+d)2,f d]!!m`

Comment: @nimi I don't even understand how that works.  You should probably just post it yourself.

Comment: It's still the same algorithm, but just a different way to pick the branch (recursively call f again vs. base case), so feel free to edit it in. `|(d,m)<-divMod x 2` is a [pattern guard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76749/34531) to bind `d` to `div x 2` and `m` to `mod x 2`. We use `m` to index the two element list `[...,...]!!m`. In case of `m==0` we return `mod(1+d)2` and in case of `m==1` `f d`.

Comment: Oh, `div`+ `mod` is still shorter than `divMod`: `f x|d<-div x 2=[mod(1+d)2,f d]!!mod x 2`

Comment: @nimi That doesn't seem to work.  It seems to have an offset of one.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have to flip the list elements: `[f d,mod(1+d)2]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoiY3P0WhQsHIzsAWyNIw1E7JLAPxNY1qDIFiaSpQPlc6UG2KjS6UaxudrpCiA9WhaRSrqAg1h@t/bmJmnoKtQko@l4KCQkFRZl6JgopCbmKBQppCtKGenpFBLLpEOkziPwA "Haskell – Try It Online").

Answer (score 3):

## x86 Machine Code, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes:

Assumes an ABI where parameters are pushed on the stack and the return value is in the `AL` register.

```
8B 44 24 04 0F BC C8 41 0F BB C8 0F 93 C0 C3
```

This is disassembled as follows:

```
_dragoncurve:
  00000000: 8B 44 24 04        mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4]
  00000004: 0F BC C8           bsf         ecx,eax
  00000007: 41                 inc         ecx
  00000008: 0F BB C8           btc         eax,ecx
  0000000B: 0F 93 C0           setae       al
  0000000E: C3                 ret
```

Comment: That looks like 366 bytes to me

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm counting the size of the CPU instruction in bytes for my answer; that's a pretty common practice on PPCG for assembly answers.

Comment: I couldn't say how common it is, [but it is definitely *wrong*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12339/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor That was an easy fix. It seems pedantic since the accepted solution is to just post the string of CPU instructions and call it "machine code" rather than assembly. The answers also highly recommend including a disassembly of the instructions in your answer.

Comment: It isn't just pedantic, it's also meaningless. There is no distinction between "machine code" and "assembly code" as far as a computer is concerned. The difference is merely one of interpretation. We assign mnemonics to machine code bytes to make them easier for humans to read. In other words, we *ungolf* the bytes to make them easier to understand.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right, though. You are *intending* to return only a single byte, in `AL`, but you claim to be returning the result in `EAX`. That means you'll have garbage in the upper bytes. So you'll either have to add extra code that clears those, or declare that you're returning a Boolean in the lower 8 bits (which would be `AL`). Hopefully that made sense; it's kind of hard to explain. Basically, just change the answer to say "return value is a Boolean in AL". And I'm not sure why you need `BTC`. `BT` would work just as well, since you're clobbering the input anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray Huh. Because of that comment I just went and re-read the documentation of `SETcc` thoroughly and it doesn't say anything about zeroing upper bytes of larger registers - it works on my machine, though. Updated my answer.

Comment: No, it absolutely does not zero the upper bytes! That has always been a serious PITA with `SETcc`, in fact, because of the possibility for partial register stalls that it introduces. Putting golfing aside for a moment, the standard idiom is to `XOR` the entire 32-bit register in advance, if possible, but you have to do it before you set the flags. If that's not possible, you can `MOVZX eax, al` after the `SETcc`. Or, sometimes you see a `MOV eax, 0` inserted immediately before the `SETcc`, since moves don't touch flags. I'd swear there was a detailed SO answer on this, but I can't find it.

Comment: @CodyGray Good to know for sure. I updated my answer to say the return value is in `AL` though, so a C prototype for this function would expect it to return a `char` and not an `int` - no harm done.

Comment: @CodyGray, there's a massive difference. Assembly code can't be executed: it has to be assembled, and the output executed.

Comment: That is irrelevant, @Peter. The assembly code is just a human-readable translation of machine code. They are exactly the same language, just in two different forms/representations. It's no different than TI BASIC, where it is commonly accepted that [we count *tokens*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/58518), instead of character bytes, because this is how the system stores them internally. The same would be true with assembly language: the instruction mnemonics are not stored as individual characters, but rather represented as bytes of equivalent machine code.

Comment: Besides, practically speaking, why would anyone *ever* enter expanded assembly language mnemonics in a code-golf competition, when they could translate them into 100% equivalent machine code, where the entry is guaranteed to be shorter for free? That alone makes a distinction between the two pointless, if not entirely absurd.

Comment: @CodyGray, how the system stores them internally is *precisely the point*. You don't pass machine code to NASM or GAS: you pass a text file. For consistency with *every other language*, that text file is the file whose length needs to be counted. The argument you're making is exactly the same argument that some people make in favour of gzipped versions of Python or whatever, to which the answer is: make an interpreter which operates on that, *defining a new language*, and claim that your file is in that new language.

Comment: There seems to me a very clear difference here between gzipped versions of Python and what I'm talking about, where these are literally two sides of the same coin, but okay. Whatever. We can play the game of labeling it "machine code" if it makes people feel better. That's just not the canonical name or representation, which makes the answers harder to find and harder to understand, and also effectively means that no one will ever enter an assembly-lang entry. But I guess I also play code golf differently than others. Creating a brand new language seems like cheating/missing the point to me.

Comment: [Similar idea, same score](https://tio.run/##VVDBbsIwDD0nX2F1q2ihQLmOjtt23Q/sksahjVScLQkIaeLbO5eWTsshtp/fi59Tq9D2WkU4AHrVONoEqCpYvH28L3qxaTpXdwIlvkhRh6NIDdoCUqOvUpzcZa4V15a0GDtBeZHqbmrAdMjFe5xBoQjF8@6h9ybKnudK@c@Pnv3IJx7RndFAFSJat2kPUpprNJ7AUgTM@M73Ug7FSVmCAQDlG12AdhQi6FZ5WC4ZuuTwc3cxUIhFQ350HjKCV9jtgaDiWJacrVYP8nC@PEuOWYJZijlzU/ykpAAq2ADlPH8g3cYHeaczuyv38ibvqzVa/y02//jaTTkTsIa1uUISTITW2KaNUCYjhDaoEGDrASfk@2xjMms32zHrfwE) in SysV ABI

Comment: In fact if you combine SysV ABI with (char) return, then you can [save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##VVDBboMwDD3HX2ExoUJLgV1X1tt23Q/sEpIUItFkS0JVaeq3M4dSpvli@/nZfnbLfT8JHvCI0vHOmtJj0@Dm7eN9M7GyG2w7MAnyBVjrTyxVUheYKnEFdraXNeeUayPYXMHF2iBmH8GF9Ch5FbiKJT4AcyrARAsB/gkRqxB4otnDKBU2Pkhty/4IoK5BOYOi5w5lpk3IDwDk8My1wQggd50oUFjjw5233RJ0yfFnFhIphppifLIOM4Ov@HxAgw35uqZot3uQo305ajllicxSmRM3lZ8mKdAUJMDktD@SbveBdNRI8uoD3GC@rRPi77L113u7xADV6F3ValN1ssW9umJCX8Je6a4PWCd3SGrPvceKbl6Q71GHZB1SVks0/QI).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda n:n&-n&n/2<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq/yVOFDUuJQuY2Ql1FfETaef3mvfuCuDnbWDKERPvLLXCbqqRLReOODtSe9@JDDSzXRcwqYmnmI/)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```js
f=
n=>!(n&-n&n/2)
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Edit: Saved 3 bytes by porting @Dennis's answer once I noticed that boolean output was acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 20 bytes

```c
f(n){n=!(n&-n&n/2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs9WUSNPTTdPLU/fSNO69n9mXolCbmJmnoYmVzUXZ1p@kQZIJE/BVsHQGkjZAGkDAyBLW1uTi5OzoAgom6ahpFqqoKSjADJQ05qrlus/AA)

Comment: This doesn't actually "work"; you are relying on a quirk of the code generator for one particular version of the compiler targeting one particular architecture, where intermediate calculations are done in the same register that is used for return values. Enabling any type of optimization, changing the target architecture, or using a different version of GCC will break this. You might as well just say "the garbage on my stack contains the right output when there is a full moon on October 13th".

Comment: While everything you say is true and code like this never be used in production code, we define languages by their implementations for the purposes of code golf. Without additional flags, this works in all recent versions of gcc and tcc, and it only has to work in *one* version to be considered valid.

Comment: *"we define languages by their implementations for the purposes of code golf"* Wait, what? So every compiler flag and every version of GCC defines a different language? You realize that's crazy, right? The C language standard is what defines the language.

Comment: Not here. If there was a C standard but no implementation, we wouldn't even consider it a language. As I said before, [the compiler defines the language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/12012). As a result, [relying on undefined behavior is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5487/12012). A different set of flags isn't considered a different language, but unless you add them to your byte count, all answers use standard compilation flags.

Comment: Wow. That's nuts. I mean, I could understand if you were saying that *implementation-defined* behavior is allowed, but undefined behavior is *not* defined by the implementation. It is literally undefined. The implementation is allowed to do random things each time. And this notion of "standard compilation flags" is something that you just invented. *My* standard compilation flags include several that break your code. And I hardly think the optimizer is non-standard. Well, clearly this site is not for me.

Comment: I'm not talking about *your* or *my* standard compilation flags; I mean the bare minimum you need to produce an executable. With C and gcc, that simply `gcc <filename>`. If you want to turn on optimizations, affect error checking either way, or include additional libraries, they contribute to your byte count. -- If you don't want to use UB in *your* answers, no problem. We're all here to have fun, but that means different things for different people. For me, that means twisting the language in any imaginable way to squeeze out the last byte.

Comment: Sure, I enjoy twisting the language in any imaginable way to squeeze out the last byte. But, as I said initially, what you're doing here is tantamount to saying the garbage on your stack contains the right output under a certain set of arbitrary conditions. That strikes me as anti-competitive (I'd say 'cheating', but you said the 'rules' explicitly allow this, so clearly it can't be cheating, but it definitely rubs me wrong.) I realize I'm free to do whatever I want, but I don't like playing games whose rules encourage nonsense submissions. There's nothing "fun" in trying to reason about UB.

Answer (score 3):

## [INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/INTERCAL), 50 bytes

```
DOWRITEIN.1DO.1<-!?1~.1'~#1DOREADOUT.1PLEASEGIVEUP
```

INTERCALs unary operators are quite suitable for this, so I decided to write my first post.

```
DO WRITE IN .1
DO .1 <- !?1~.1'~#1
DO READ OUT .1
PLEASE GIVE UP
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer.

```
Bt0ṖṪṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//QnQw4bmW4bmq4bmG/zk5w4figqxH/w)

### Longer programs

- 7 bytes: [`Họ¡2&2Ị`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/j4e7eQwuN1Iwe7u76b2l5uP1R0xr3/wA)
- 7 bytes: [`Bt0ṫ-ḄỊ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@pxODhztW6D3e0PNzd9d/S8nD7o6Y17v8B)

Comment: Hmm...well, you can just do `ṖṪṆ` (as my deleted answer) instead of `ṫ-ḄỊ`.

Comment: Another one for your 7-byte list: `BUḌDḊḢ¬`

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 19 bytes

```
&#;:2%\2/\#;_;@.!%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X03Z2spINcZIP0bZOt7aQU9R1ej/fyNDYzMA)

```
&#                       Initial input: Read a number an skip the next command
  ;:2%\2/\#;_;           Main loop: (Direction: East)
   :2%                    Duplicate the current number and read the last bit
      \2/                 Swap the first two items on stack (last bit and number)
                          and divide the number by two => remove last bit
         \                swap last bit and number again
          #;_;            If the last bit is 0, keep going East and jump to the beginning of the loop
                          If the last bit is 1, turn West and jump to the beginning of the loop, but in a different direction.
&#;           @.!%2      End: (Direction: West)
&#                        Jump over the input, wrap around
                 %2       Take the number mod 2 => read the last bit
               .!         Negate the bit and print as a number
              @          Terminate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 34 bytes

```matlab
@(x)~(k=[de2bi(x),0])(find(k,1)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzTiPbNjol1SgpE8jRMYjV1EjLzEvRyNYx1NQ21PyfpmFooPkfAA)

**Explanation:**

```matlab
@(x)                               % Anonymous function taking a decimal number as input
    ~....                          % Negate whatever comes next
     (   de2bi(x)   )              % Convert x to a binary array that's conveniently 
                                   % ordered with the least significant bits first
        [de2bi(x),0]               % Append a zero to the end, to avoid out of bound index
     (k=[de2bi(x),0])              % Store the vector as a variable 'k'
                     (find(k,1)    % Find the first '1' in k (the least significant 1-bit)
                               +1  % Add 1 to the index to get the next bit
     (k=[de2bi(x),0])(find(k,1)+1) % Use as index to the vector k to get the correct bit
```

Comment: How come I never heard of de2bi... :O

Answer (score 2):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code-page)

```
::0-&2*&¬
```

### Explanation

Take input as 3 for example.

```
::0-&2*&1≥
               implicitly push command line argument       [3]
::             duplicate twice                             [3, 3, 3]
  0            push 0 on to the stack                      [3, 3, 3, 0]
   -           pop 0 and 3 and push 0 - 3                  [3, 3, -3]
    &          pop -3 and 3 and push -3 & 3 (bitwise AND)  [3, 1]
     2         push 2 on to the stack                      [3, 1, 2]
      *        pop 2 and 1 and push 2 * 1                  [3, 2]
       &       pop 2 and 3 and push 2 & 3                  [2]
        ¬      pop 2 and push ¬ 2 (logical NOT)            [0]
               implicit output                             []
```

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 71 bytes

```lisp
(load library
(q((x)(not(nth(c 0(to-base 2 x))(last-index(to-base 2 x)1
```

Anonymous function that takes a number and returns 0 or 1. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VckxDoAgDAXQ3VN0/B1IkEtwjiImkiAgdMDT4@xbn6by5jTaWshVIuUUuvR3QySPB5iMUhVFLxxkodUEGSc5mszIMtSkEs/5i33hlkaesGslZ5nXBw)

#### Ungolfed/explanation

Surprisingly, tinylisp's library lets us implement the spec almost directly.

```lisp
(load library)

(lambda (x)                   ; Anonymous function with one argument
  (not                        ; Logical negation of
    (nth                      ; The element of _ at index __:
      (cons 0 (to-base 2 x))  ; The binary representation of x with a 0 prepended
      (last-index             ; Index of the last occurrence
        (to-base 2 x)         ; in the binary representation of x
        1)))))                ; of 1
```

Prepending a 0 handles the "previous bit" logic by shifting all elements down one spot, and it keeps us from walking off the left end of the list when there is only a single 1 bit.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
t4*YF1)Z.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8REK9LNUDNKr@7/f1MA) Or see the [first 100 outputs](https://tio.run/##y00syflvaGBgpeTwv8REK9LNUDNKr@5/rFrGfwA).

#### Explanation

```
t    % Implicit input. Duplicate
4*   % Multiply by 4. This ensures that the input is a multiple of 2, and
     % takes into account that bit positions are 1 based
YF   % Exponents of prime factorization
1)   % Get first exponent, which is that of factor 2
Z.   % Get bit of input at that (1-based) position
~    % Negate. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## Submission:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```python
x=input()
while~-x&1:x/=2
print 1-x/2%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMntU63Qs3QqkLf1oiroCgzr0TBULdC30gVqNDI0NgMAA)

-2 bytes thanks to FryAmTheEggman

## Initial Solution:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda x:1-int(bin(x)[bin(x).rfind('1')-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCylA3M69EIykzT6NCMxpC6RWlZealaKgbqmvqGsZq/i8oAilJ0zAyNDbT1PwPAA)

Comment: So which one is your submission?

Comment: @LeakyNun The first one because it's shorter; the second one was my original submission. Should I post them separately?

Comment: `~-x&1` works for the while condition instead, I think.

Comment: (I forget the username); I rejected your edit because edits to golf other people's code is not advised on PPCG. You can post suggestions (btw, thanks @FryAmTheEggman), but please do not make golfing edits. Thanks!

Comment: @StewieGriffin Ah yes, thanks. Unfortunately I can't ping the user because the edit was rejected.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 20 bytes

```
n->kronecker(-1,n)>0
```

Using the [Kronecker symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjBCcAgDAXQVUJPBgyYAcwupWgR4Suh@6de3uHt24e8OzrVgNj0hfbM5kk0g61EX55AlTSTlpJp@8B35iKxQ09g5vgB)

Answer (score 1):

## SCALA, 99(78?) chars, 99(78?) bytes

```
if(i==0)print(1)else
print(if(('0'+i.toBinaryString).reverse.dropWhile(x=>x=='0')(1)=='1')0 else 1)
```

where `i` is the input.

As you can see, I do save 21 bytes if I don't take care of the zero (as the author did in his test case) :

```
print(if(('0'+i.toBinaryString).reverse.dropWhile(x=>x=='0')(1)=='1')0 else 1)
```

This is my first codegolf so I hope I did well :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xb8IwEIVn/CtOWeJTRGQXiQHVSLAxdOrQpYtJLuAqOkeOQalQf3t6iKpiu7v33XtvbHzv53j8oibDmw8MNGXidoTdMNzUoqUO2uRPkZtLupIOmwNnvM2h08E5g0MKnLVF6kdSj0UkXZqyCnWO@8A@fb9nEU5YJ7pSGqluUxw@zqEnPbnt5JzQKB4y2BIN3L3A4vyjVBeTZnhdgoEcwRqD0ukRU3xyUXFVwHILBUrTp5aMSp7/uRe7Wv9hz9T9LOD8Cw) Though it's quite long to compute lol.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>35</s> 31 bytes

```c
f(x){return~x&1?f(x/2):!(x&2);}
```

Switched to a recursive implementation.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoMwEEbhfU7xK1RmsKXGpan0LCVtZBZNJUQISHr1GJfvffa2WFuKo8R7@MQt@H/q9LP2feSpodSNbHIRH/F9iSfeFeB@gc4jszbymPUwGOl7ME4E1lDRUXt5o73CkTDYVMkqq3IA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 17 bytes

```
n->(n&2*(n&-n))<1
```

Straightforward port of [LeakyNun's Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128877/58251). I'm not familiar enough with bitwise operations and operator precedence to see a shorter solution; maybe there's a way to avoid the extra parentehesis?

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 93 bytes

```
HZABCDEFG,t
 ))))))))^~S
H\\\\\\\/v~a
G\\\\\\/v'
F\\\\\/v'
E\\\\/v'
D\\\/v'
C\\/v'
B\/v'
A/-'
```

Takes input as little endian bytes. (The TIO has a bit of python that does this for you). Gives output as either `0x0` or `0x1`. (The TIO uses xxd to inspect the value).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLasMwELzrK5ZcZNFEog20gTwgDzu59dBbKQ1@KLHAlYS0aW0I@XVXTpzSOczM7sLOslnqyzZPERZgnTnyvFQWZjOg8WtC2937crXexMl2iARYj8/LG9l93CC@LynZ3j0lyZ@L72bT6/omqysvxYi2IYKQLpsrbU/IURk4g22wNHoMoxwG6ssah@AbP4Ua5qA0RqHgHguluZNpETE2hb5lwo7sdDhIx3@cQhnVHM0@a1D6KPhM4b6S@ohlxB5emBCTIXRD4wrp5rRSiJWkjA3CEcJYFN0vrsRt8@87Z6jron16HD//Ag)

#### How do it this?

Chip looks at input one byte at a time, so handling multibyte input adds some bulk, but not near as much as I had feared.

Let's go into it:

```
HZABCDEFG
```

These are `HZ`, high bit of the previous byte (if there was one), and `A`-`G`, the seven lower bits of the current byte. These are used to locate the lowest set bit of the number.

```
        ,t
))))))))^~S
```

When the lowest set bit is found, we have a few things to do. This first chunk says "if we have a set bit (the `)`'s), then stop `S`uppressing the output, and `t`erminate after we print the answer.

```
H\\\\\\\/v~a
G\\\\\\/v'
...
A/-'
```

Whichever bit of the current byte (`A`-`H`) is only preceded by a bunch of zeroes then a one (`\` and `/`: these look at the bits directly north of them; we can trust that all previous bits were zero) is passed through to the wires on the right (`v`, `'`, ...), then whichever value it is is inverted and given as the low bit of output (`~a`).

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 bytes

```apl
1≠¯1⊥2↑⍸∘⌽∘⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/3/BR54JD6w0fdS01etQ28VHvjkcdMx717AWRXUv@pz1qm/Cot@9RV/Oh9cYg@b6pwUHOQDLEwzP4fxlItm8ql6GCoYKBAoSE0DAWMh8makBAHl2/AYX6CdkPN5/rUdeicqCX0g6teNS72dDAgKvsUefCcgA)

Took the idea of using `⍸` from [Razetime's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211228/78410).

#### How it works

```apl
1≠¯1⊥2↑⍸∘⌽∘⊤  ⍝ Input: n
           ⊤  ⍝ Binary representation of n
         ⌽∘   ⍝ Reverse
       ⍸∘     ⍝ Get indices of ones, in increasing order
              ⍝   LSB index (l) comes first, and the next number is l+1
              ⍝   iff the bit on the left of LSB is also 1
     2↑       ⍝ Take first two numbers, filling with 0 if too short
  ¯1⊥         ⍝ From [a, b] compute -a + b
1≠            ⍝ Is it not equal to 1?
```

Equivalent non-extended program:

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
1≠¯1⊥2↑∘⍸∘⌽2∘⊥⍣¯1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/BR54JD6w0fdS01etQ28VHHjEe9O0Bkz14jENW19FHvYqD8/7RHbRMe9fY96mo@tN4YpLJvanCQM5AM8fAM/l8Gku2bymWoYKhgoAAhITSMhcyHiRoQkEfXb0ChfkL2w83netS1qBzopbRDKx71bjY0MOAqe9S5sBwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
¬!2↓¬↔Θḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9odXNr/23igoHhuKMxMDD/wqwhMuKGk8Ks4oaUzpjhuIv//w)

```
¬          # logical NOT of
 !2        # the second element
   ↓¬      # after chopping-off initial zeros
     ↔     # of the reverse of
      Θḋ   # the binary digits of the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
~1=-/|-2#&2\
```

Modeled after [@Bubbler's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211251/98547).

- `2\` convert input to base-2
- `-2#&` get the last two indices containing 1's
- `-/|` subtract the smaller index from the larger one
- `~1=` if the last truthy index isn't preceded by another truthy value, return 0. otherwise, return 1

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nqs7QVle/RtdIWc0o5n@RlaGCoYKBAoSE0DAWMh8makBAHl2/AYX6CdkPN5@rqC5N3VBb0dDA4D8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
éò/ú╗
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82952fa3bb&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A2136&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
b0PṪt⌐
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJiMFDhuap04oyQIiwiIiwiMjEzNiJd)

```
b      # Convert to binary
 0P    # Strip zeroes
   Ṫt  # Second-to-last item
     ⌐ # The NOT of that
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 83 bytes

```
(load library
(d F(q((x)(i(h x)x(F(t x
(d G(q((x)(- 1(h(t(F(reverse(c 0(to-base 2 x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclLCoAgFAXQeau4w@sg6AMtodahJShIH5V4rt4KOtOT/V6CT2etDIfeELyJOpaGG2ZepCh6OogSzsyQL5Y/WvR0zG9Ee9uYLFd0zEdrdLIYIJULhn6cVH0A)

fixed with dlosc's help.

Comment: Doesn't work for powers of 2--you'll want to cons a 0 to the front of the binary representation before reversing it, I think.

Comment: Also, `def` can be `d`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10 8</s> 9 bytes

```
!+¢g¢a1 É
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/X1H70KL0Q4sSDRUOd/7/b2RobAYA)

## Explanation

```
!+¢   g    a1 É
!+Us2 gUs2 a1 -1 # Implicit input (U) as number
!+               # Return the boolean NOT of
      g          #   the character at index
       Us2       #     the input converted to binary
           a1    #     the index of its last 1
              -1 #     minus 1
      g          #   in string
  Us2            #     the input converted to binary
```

Comment: This returns `false` for everything because the character (0 or 1) is always a string.

Comment: Oops, should've noticed that... Fixed now

Comment: Looks like it [fails for `1`](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ISuiZ6JhMSDJ&input=MQo=) now.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>53</s> 34 bytes

```
a=>eval("for(;~a&1;a/=2);~a>>1&1")
```

Comment: 42 bytes: `a=>!+(a=a.toString(2))[a.lastIndexOf(1)-1]`

Comment: I already found a shorter (mathematical) solution...

Comment: Nice :) Mind if I post that 42 byte one?

Comment: @Shaggy, no not at all

Answer (score 0):

## PHP>=7.1, 32 bytes

```php
<?=1^!trim(decbin($argn),0)[-2];
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9959bce92910a50e7b16dc647ec34042499ae1e0)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 40 bytes

```php
for($i=$argn;$i%2<1;)$i/=2;echo$i/2%2^1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMClkliUnmerZKRk/T8tv0hDJdMWLGKtkqlqZGNoramSqW9rZJ2anJEPZBmpGsUZWv//DwA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

```php
<?=1^preg_match("#110*$#",decbin($argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMClkliUnmerZK5kzWVvBxS0NYwrKEpNj89NLEnO0FBSNjQ00FJRVtJJSU1OyszTACvX1LT@/x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 56 bytes

```
(defun f(n)(if(oddp n)(- 1(mod #1=(ash n -1)2))(f #1#)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYsxCsMwEAS/stjNXmHwpc9jRC6HBZZO2EqbrytKNzMwrzPfbQza2z8VzirMzjBrmLhBWcKw6pPpPlCxqTxE6DOtIjJ4RjR4XMjwKwoUPaD7Dgtw9pI6OpZvwjId@T/9AA)

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 24 bytes (6 instrs)

```
00000000: 36ff0000 c8ffff00 3bffff01 c80000ff  6”¡¡Ṁ””¡;””¢Ṁ¡¡”
00000010: 73000001 f8010000                    s¡¡¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

Disassembled

```
dragon  NEGU $255,0,$0      // t = -n
        AND  $255,$255,$0   // t &= n (gets last 1 bit)
        SLU  $255,$255,1    // t <<= 1
        AND  $0,$0,$255     // n &= t
        ZSZ  $0,$0,1        // n = !n
        POP  1,0            // return n
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
&n)Ñ&U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=Jm4p0SZV&input=MjEzNgotTg)

```
&n)Ñ&U     :Implicit input of integer U
&          :Bitwise AND of U with
 n         :Its negation
  )        :Group that together
   Ñ       :Multiply by 2
    &U     :Bitwise AND with U
```